# Outbound networking HTTP trigger to App store

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
import iapReceiptValidator from 'iap-receipt-validator';

const password = 'abcdefghijkac64beb900889e1'; // Shared Secret from iTunes connect
const production = false; // use sandbox or production url for validation


async validate(receiptData) {
    try {
        const validationData = await validateReceipt(receiptData);

        // check if Auto-Renewable Subscription is still valid
         validationData['latest_receipt_info'][0].expires_date > today
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.valid, err.error, err.message)
    }
}

exports.validateReceipt = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

const validateReceipt = iapReceiptValidator(password, production);


}
```

This is what I have so far. I am using [this](https://github.com/sibelius/iap-receipt-validator) external library. I am using firebase cloud functions and I am on flame plan. I want to make POST request to send receipt JSON object to app store server for auto-renewable purchase verification. I am not sure how to go forward with this. Can i please get some help in regards to structuring my cloud function. The firebase documentation isn't very helpful.

Appreciate any help!